# Search all my Thunderbird address books?

Tags: thunderbird, search, contacts

I have a bunch of different Thunderbird address books set up, and I'd like an interface (I'll take something command line) that lets me search them all. Currently, if I see that something is prompting me to use an old addy in my auto complete, I have to open my contacts and search each address book separately to find the offending bad address. I'd love to search them all in one pass.

Answer (score 2):

try Contact Tabs. It adds a search box to Thunderbird where you can search all adressbooks at once.

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/contact-tabs/